# pyspark joining dataframes with struct column

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have df1:

```
df1 = spark.sql("select id,col from table1")
df1.show(100,False)
+---+----------------+
|id |col             |
+---+----------------+
|1  |abc             |
|1  |lmn             |
|1  |xyz             |
|2  |abc             |
|2  |ijk             |
|2  |lmn             |
|3  |def             |
|3  |lmn             |
+---+----------------+
```

I have another dataframe created from table2 which has a struct type column:

```
spark.sql("select id,struct_col from table2").printSchema()
root
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- struct_col: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- abc: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- start_time: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- end_time: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- def: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- start_time: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- end_time: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- ijk: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- start_time: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- end_time: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)


df2 = spark.sql("select id,struct_col from table2").show(100,False)
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |struct_col                                                                                                         |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[[2021-02-02, 2021-02-08, version1],,,[2021-02-02, 2021-02-09, version2],[2021-02-02, 2021-02-09, version8]]       |
|2  |[[2021-02-02, 2021-02-18, version21],,[2021-02-03, 2021-03-09, version2],[2021-02-07, 2021-03-21, version14],]      |
|3  |[,[2021-02-07, 2021-04-07, version11],,[2021-02-09, 2021-03-31, version15],]                                         |
+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Basically, if I query start_time, end_time, version of all. It shows like below.

```
df3  = 
spark.sql("select id, 
struct_col.abc.start_time,struct_col.abc.end_time,struct_col.abc.version,
struct_col.def.start_time,struct_col.def.end_time,struct_col.def.version,
struct_col.ijk.start_time,struct_col.ijk.end_time,struct_col.ijk.version,
struct_col.lmn.start_time,struct_col.lmn.end_time,struct_col.lmn.version,
struct_col.xyz.start_time,struct_col.xyz.end_time,struct_col.xyz.version
from table2
").show(100,False)

+---+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|id |struct_col.abc.start_time|struct_col.abc.end_time|struct_col.abc.version|struct_col.def.start_time|struct_col.def.end_time|struct_col.def.version|struct_col.ijk.start_time|struct_col.ijk.end_time|struct_col.ijk.version|struct_col.lmn.start_time|struct_col.lmn.end_time|struct_col.lmn.version|struct_col.xyz.start_time|struct_col.xyz.end_time|struct_col.xyz.version|
+---+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|1  |2021-02-02               |2021-02-08             |version1              |null                     |null                   |null                  |null                     |null                   |null                  |2021-02-02               |2021-02-09             |version2              |2021-02-02               |2021-02-09             |version8              |
|2  |2021-02-02               |2021-02-18             |version21             |null                     |null                   |null                  |2021-02-03               |2021-03-09             |version2              |2021-02-07               |2021-03-21             |version14             |null                     |null                   |null                  |
|3  |null                     |null                   |null                  |2021-02-07               |2021-04-07             |version11             |null                     |null                   |null                  |2021-02-09               |2021-03-31             |version15             |null                     |null                   |null                  |
+---+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

I am looking to join `df1` and `df3` (or `df2`). So that I get `start_time,end_time,version` for each combination.

I am trying to join the regular way like `spark.sql("select df1.* from df1 inner join df2 on df1.id = df2.id")` but I don't think I can achieve this straightway of join. Looking for some help here.

Expected Output Dataframe:

```
+---+----------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|id |col             |start_time    |end_time    |version    |
+---+----------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|1  |abc             |2021-02-02    |2021-02-08  |version1   |
|1  |lmn             |2021-02-02    |2021-02-09  |versio2    |
|1  |xyz             |2021-02-02    |2021-02-09  |version8   |
|2  |abc             |2021-02-02    |2021-02-18  |version21  |
|2  |ijk             |2021-02-03    |2021-03-09  |version2   |
|2  |lmn             |2021-02-07    |2021-03-21  |version14  |
|3  |def             |2021-02-07    |2021-04-07  |version11  |
|3  |lmn             |2021-02-09    |2021-03-31  |version15  |
+---+----------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After joining on `id`, you can get the column names in the struct `struct_col` (with `df2.select("struct_col.*").columns`), and using list comprehension you create an array of the fields you want from each nested struct, then explode to get the desired result:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"), ["id"], "left") \
    .withColumn(
    "struct_values",
    F.array(*[
        F.when(
            F.col("col") == F.lit(s),
            F.struct(
                F.col(f"struct_col.{s}.start_time").alias("start_time"),
                F.col(f"struct_col.{s}.end_time").alias("end_time"),
                F.col(f"struct_col.{s}.version").alias("version"),
            )
        )
        for s in df2.select("struct_col.*").columns
    ])
).selectExpr(
    "id", "col", "explode(filter(struct_values, x -> x not null)) as struct_values"
).select("id", "col", "struct_values.*")
```